# Android - MediaPlayer + PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating application for listening radio streams via WiFi & 3G network.

I am using native MediaPlayer. Unfortunately when screen goes black and phone goes into standby mode mediaplayer starts stopping playing the music.

I have added:

```
mp.setWakeMode(myContext, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

But there wasn't almost any change (just stop playing and in the next 3 seconds start playing again..) only FULL_WAKE_LOCK and SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK is working as I expected...

In my device I have set option that prevents wifi to sleep.

I was trying to add my cusom WAKE_LOCK

```
        mp.setWakeMode(this.getBaseContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "testa");
        wl.acquire();
```

But it didn't work as well. Only FULL_WAKE_LOCK works, but I do not want to drain battery with screen on :(.

I have HTC Desire with Android 2.2. Do you have any ideas how to prevent MediaPlayer stop playing internet radio stream while telephone is in standby mode?

Comment: How are you playing your music?  Is the player running the UI thread or in another thread?  Could it be that your thread is going to sleep with the screen?

Comment: Another possibility is the WiFi is going to sleep with the screen and cutting off your stream. WiFiManager may need a lock as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jerry points out, you may need to keep a WiFi lock is the stream is coming over WiFi. The other thing is, when are you acquiring the wakelock? You should acquire it when your app starts, not wait for the screen to go off. You may not be able to acquire the wakelock before the device goes to sleep. Also, you will need the WAKE_LOCK permission if you don't already have it.

Comment: Thx... this solved my problem! WIFI_Lock and everything is ok!

Comment: Dear Radzio,will really appreciate if you can let me know what all you did to keep the stream playing, I tried the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK but the stream still stops, I am not able to find out how to apply WiFi_Lock?